# jquery select (find) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table on my page html :

```
<table id="myTab">
    <tr>
        <td class="reference">1</td>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td>Info item - 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="reference">2</td>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>Info item - 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="reference">3</td>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>Info item - 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="reference">4</td>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>Info item - 4</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

How I can select an element of my table with class reference innerHtml value=3?

```
var el = $(myTab).find('???')
```

Comment: I encourage you to read the jQuery documentation, especially http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. You will save a lot of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want a reference to just that `td` element, and the markup you've shown is the extent of your current structure, you can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
var elem = $(".reference:contains('3')");
```

If you have other `td` elements containing the character `3` (e.g. `13`) they will also be matched. In that case, it's probably better to use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var elem = $(".reference").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === "3";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = $("#myTab").find("td.reference:contains(3)")
```

...will work assuming the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is good enough - noting that it matches on (in this case) "3" anywhere within the content of the element.

If you need an exact match you can use `.filter()`:

```
var el = $("#myTab").find("td.reference")
                    .filter(function() { return $(this).html() === "3"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a pure javascript:

```
 function func() {
        var myTab= document.getElementById('myTab');
        var len = myTab.rows.length;
        for (var r = 0; r < len; r++) {
            var rowLen = myTab.rows[r].cells.length;
            for (var cel = 0; cel < rowLen; cel++) {
                if(myTab.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML === "3" && myTab.rows[r].cells[c].className === "reference")
                {
                   alert("found:"+myTab.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```